# Javascript Formatting Numbers With Commas and Dot

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript code to formatting my input number. For example when user type : 100000 it will convert automatically to 100,000 and if user type 1000.22 it will result 1,000.22. I have create code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.angka').on("keyup click", function(event){
      // skip for arrow keys
      if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
      var $this = $(this);
      var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");
      
      var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));
      
      // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
      $this.val(num2);
  });
});

function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){
    if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){
        return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)
    }
    return convertString;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="angka form-control" name="hargak" onkeyup="tots();" />
```

So all my input textbox which has class 'angka' will be converted. It works if I type it without decimals (10000, 20000, etc). But when I use decimal, these code gone wrong (1000.22 will result 1,000,.22) anyone can fix this code?

Comment: `num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,")` inserts a comma after every 3 characters, even if the character is a decimal point.

Comment: You should split the input at the `.`, and only add the commas to the part before the `.`.

Comment: for Chrome 24+, Firefox 29+, IE11, Edge and Opera 15+ - you could use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility...
You should also accept navigating with arrows left and right...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.angka').on("keyup click", function(event){
      // skip for arrow keys
      if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
      var $this = $(this);
      var num = $this.val();
      var decs = num.split(".");
      num = decs[0];
      num = num.replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");
      
      var num2 = RemoveRogueChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));
      if(decs.length > 1) {
          num2 += '.' + decs[1];
      }
      $this.val(num2);
  });
});

function RemoveRogueChar(convertString){
    if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){
        return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)
    }
    
    return convertString;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="angka form-control" name="hargak" onkeyup="tots();" />
```

Comment: thanks, it work well.. if I accept navigating with arrow, sometimes the js not working well for example, if I type 10000 and it result 10,000 then I use arrow to put a number between them, it would result 10,2,000, that's why I block it. thanks again..